# How do you call render() if it can't be in your Rmd file?

Tags: r-markdown, render

I would like to end an Rmd file with the `render()` command to create an (in my case) Word document of the finished report. The reason I'm using the command `render()` instead of the Knit button is to manipulate where it stores my output file.

If I have the line `render(file.Rmd)` in my the same Rmd that I'm trying to render I get two errors.
If I have named chunks, the first error that it will print is:

`Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src) : duplicate label 'setup'`

If I do not have named chunks, it goes through the loop of rendering over and over again and gives me the error:

`Error in sink(con, split = debug) : sink stack is full`

What I understand now is that when the call is made in the same Rmd, the process will recursively analyze the Rmd over and over again.

**So, how do you call `render()` if it can't be in your file?**

My solution as of now is to comment out the render command, save the file, uncomment it, and then run it. But this seems awfully clunky.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: You would typically call `render()` from a separate `.R` script. This also has the benefit of allowing you to keep your render calls saved in that script, making your process more reproducible.

Comment: Second @joshpk's suggestion. Just have a master `.R` script that calls `.Rmd` files one by one. Save and re-read `.RData` files if needed